# NSRegularExpression not matching

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, nsregularexpression

So I have a string:

```
users/9881570/?access_token=
```

that I try to match with the regex:

```
 NSRegularExpression * regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"users/\\d/?access_token=" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

        NSArray* wordArray = [regex matchesInString:self.currentRequestURL_ 
                                            options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [self.currentRequestURL_ length])];
```

However, the wordArray has a count of 0. Why is this not matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, you need to escape the question mark, and for another you need a plus sign (+) after your \d to indicate 1 *or more* numbers.  As it is now you only look for one digit.

```
@"users/\\d+/\\?access_token="
```

Comment: For @adit there are many online sites that let you test regular expressions.  I tested the one in this answer here: http://regexpal.com/ and it works (make sure to unescape the backslashes).

Comment: @JeremyP Wow, this one is pretty!  I was ballsy and didn't test it before I added it >< and I usually use regextester.com but I want to start using this one.  Also, here is a cheat sheet for regex http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Answer (score 0):

Because the question mark is a special character in regular expressions, and it needs to be escaped.

Comment: so meaning: @"users/\\d//?access_token="?, coz I tried that too and it didn't work